# DirectX 9 Light projection

Tags: shaders, directx, directx9, shadow-mapping

I am trying to see changes of component 'z' from light space. In vertex shader component 'z' divide 'w' is not 0. But after sending float4 with texcoord1 to pixel shader its 0. All matrices are good. Here is the code:

```
float4x4 MatWorld;
float4x4 MatView;
float4x4 MatProjection;

float4 LightViewMatrix;
float4 LightProjectionMatrix;
float4 LightPosition;

texture tex0;

sampler2D ShadowMap = sampler_state
{
    texture = tex0;
};


struct VertexOut
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 lightViewPosition : TEXCOORD1;
};

struct VertexIn
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};


VertexOut VSLight(VertexIn In)
{
    VertexOut Out;

    In.position.w = 1;
    Out.position = mul(In.position, MatWorld);
    Out.lightViewPosition = Out.position;
    Out.lightViewPosition = mul(Out.lightViewPosition, LightViewMatrix);
    Out.lightViewPosition = mul(Out.lightViewPosition, LightProjectionMatrix);

    Out.position = mul(Out.position, MatView);
    Out.position = mul(Out.position, MatProjection);


    Out.tex = In.tex;
    return Out;
}


float4 PSLight(float4 Color : COLOR, float2 tex : TEXCOORD0, float4 lightViewPosition : TEXCOORD1) : COLOR
{
    float depth = lightViewPosition.z / lightViewPosition.w;
    if (depth == 0)
    {
        return float4(0, 0, 0, 1);
    }
    return float4(depth, 0, 0, 1);
}


technique T1
{
    pass P0
    {   
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 VSLight();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PSLight();
    }
};
```

All objects are black. Sorry my english is slightly poor.